# Black map after attempt to style by column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, csv, style, color

I'm very new to QGIS.

I have a shapefile of NYC census tracts and 2 csv info files with tract info joined with it. I'm trying to style the individual tracts to be filled with a different color based on the income of that tract (that info is in one of the columns of the csv file). 
In order to do that, I went to Layer Properties > Style and chose Categorized from the top drop-down. I then selected the income column and hit classify to display the color-coded contents. Once everything looked good, I pressed okay, and suddenly the map turned black, momentarily flashing random tracts until stopping.

It looks like this:
[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Guessing since you don't show the layer properties: the border width seems to be extremely wide. Could it be that the borders are covering up everything?

Comment: @underdark, how would I check that?

Comment: ... in the layer properties ...

Comment: Turns out I had one area that covered the entire perimeter of the city. Once I removed it, everything worked.